# In Eclipse, can I choose the version of Scala for my project?

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

Currently I'm using Scala IDE, and the version of Scala it's using for my project is 2.9.2. Preferably I'd like to choose 2.8.1, and am not sure how to select a version of the Scala Library.

Is there any way to change the version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://scala-ide.org/docs/user/gettingstarted.html

"The list of URLs of the different update sites are available in the download area. The release ones are in the current section. Scala IDE is linked to specific version of Scala, so you have to decide which one you are going to use:

- release-29 provides support for projects using Scala 2.9.x (2.9.0-1 or 2.9.1). This is the current version of Scala. Pick this one if you are unsure.
- release-28 provides support for projects using Scala 2.8.x (2.8.1 or 2.8.2)."

So you have to install release-28 Scala IDE to compile your Scala project with version 2.8.1 .

The release site can be found here:
http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html

Comment: And you can also try out the (yet) unreleased Scala 2.10 using a [milestone](http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html) or a [nightly](http://scala-ide.org/download/nightly.html)